# rxjava - getting response and inserting diff parallelly

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, observable

I am using `rxjava` for parallel processing of two requests using `Observable.zip`. What I am trying to do is , in one `observable say response` I am getting one response and in other `observable say diff` I am trying to get the response and save this difference in DB. The problem is I am not sure how to achieve my requirement as the `diff observable` is not getting completed if `response observable` gets the response

Here is what I am doing ...

```
public ServiceResponse getDummyResponse(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String prodId){
    Observable<ServiceResponse> subInfoDummyObservable = getDummyResonseGenericObservable();
    Observable<ServicesDiff> reObservable = getServicesDiffGenericObservable(serviceRequest, prodId);

    Observable<ServiceResponse> responseObservable = Observable.zip(
            subInfoDummyObservable,
            reObservable,
            new Func2<ServiceResponse, ServicesDiff, ServiceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public ServiceResponse call(ServiceResponse serviceResponse, ServicesDiff diffResponse) {
                    return serviceResponse;
                }
            }
    );

    ServiceResponse serviceResponse = responseObservable.toBlocking().single();

    return serviceResponse;
}

Observable<ServiceResponse> getDummyResonseGenericObservable() {
    return GenericHystrixCommand.toObservable("getDummyResonseGenericObservable", "getDummyResonseGenericObservable", () -> new ServiceResponse(),(t) -> {return null;} );
}

Observable<ServicesDiff> getServicesDiffGenericObservable(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String prodId) {
    return GenericHystrixCommand.toObservable("getServicesDiffGenericObservable", "getServicesDiffGenericObservable", () -> getBothServiceResponses(serviceRequest, prodId),(t) -> {return null;} );
}

public ServicesDiff getBothServiceResponses(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String prodId) {
    Observable<String> service1ResponseObservable = getService1GenericObservable(prodId);
    Observable<ServiceResponse> service2ResponseObservable = getService2GenericObservable(serviceRequest, prodId);

    Observable<ServicesDiff> observable = Observable.zip(
            service1ResponseObservable, service2ResponseObservable,
            new Func2<String, ServiceResponse, ServicesDiff>() {
                @Override
                public ServicesDiff call(String service1Response, ServiceResponse service2Response) {
                    return aggregate(service1Response, service2Response); // never reaches this point**********
                }
            }
    );
    ServicesDiff response = observable.toBlocking().single();

    return response;
}
```

I am inserting the diff to DB in `aggregate` method but it never reaches to `aggregate` at all. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: your code sample is not clear to me, what is the relation between the getBothServiceResponses method, where the problem resides, to the rest of the code?
what are the two observables you're zipping at getBothServiceResponses ?

Comment: I agree, the code needs clarification. the first three methods never get called, so we don't know what the observables look like in the 4th method `getBothServiceResponses()` where your problem lies

Answer (score 0):

`Observable` are a description of how to consume data. In your code sample, you don't subscribe, you don't actually consume the data. You just described how to request, but the subscribe part, the part that trigger the requests, is missing.

So if I rewrite a little your code:

```
class Aggregate {
    Aggregate(String reponse, ServicesDiff diff) {
        ...
    }
}

Observable<String> getService1GenericObservable(String prodId) {
    ...
}

Observable<ServicesDiff> getServicesDiffGenericObservable(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String prodId) {
    ...
}

public Observable<Aggregate> getBothServiceResponses(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String prodId) {
    Observable<String> service1ResponseObservable = getService1GenericObservable(prodId);
    Observable<ServiceResponse> service2ResponseObservable = getService2GenericObservable(serviceRequest, prodId);

    return Observable<Aggregate> observable = Observable.zip(
            service1ResponseObservable, service2ResponseObservable,
            new Func2<String, ServiceResponse, ServicesDiff>() {
                @Override
                public ServicesDiff call(String service1Response, ServiceResponse service2Response) {
                    return aggregate(service1Response, service2Response);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

You will just have to do this to access the result aggregate:

```
getBothServiceResponses(serviceRequest, prodId).subscribe(...)
```